# Eliminar ceros de una cadena en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy normalizando un campo que es para telefonos, se usa una función personalizada, los telefonos deberian quedar con 8 caraceteres pero esta quedando con 12 y los últimos 4 son 0 (ceros).

Ejemplo:

- formato de entrada = `["11232323230000"]`
- formato de salida(funcion aplicada) = `232323230000`
- formato de como deberia quedar= `23232323`

para tratar  eliminar los ultimos 4 agregue  la siguiente línea en la función

```
 IF (right(@F_NormPhone,8) = '0000') and left(@f_normphone,1) = '4'
        select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,8, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 4)
```

pero aun asi, no me esta eliminando los `0`

Como ejemplo un número más real de teléfono, nos envian con el formato

```````
//011455656100``````
```````

Dejo una parte de la función.

```
IF CHARINDEX('/',@F_NormPhone, 1) >0 
    SELECT @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,1, CHARINDEX('/', @F_NormPhone, 1) - 1)

IF CHARINDEX('int',@F_NormPhone, 1) >0 
    SELECT @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,1, CHARINDEX('int', @F_NormPhone, 1) - 1)


IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,4) = '0000')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,4, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 3)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,3) = '000')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,3, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 2)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,2) = '00')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,2, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 1)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,7) = '1115411')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,8, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 7)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,6) = '545411')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,7, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 6)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,6) = '115411')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,7, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 6)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,5) = '54011')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,6, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 5)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,5) = '54911')
    select  @F_NormPhone = '15' + SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,6, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 5)

--IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,3) = '549')
--  select  @F_NormPhone = '0' + SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,4, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 3)


IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,4) = '0054')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,5, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 4)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,5) = '05411')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,6, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 5)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,4) = '5411')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,5, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 4)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,3) = '054')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,4, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 3)
IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,3) = '911')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,4, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 3)
        IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,3) = '954')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,4, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 3)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,2) = '54' AND Len(@F_NormPhone) > 8)
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,3, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 2)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,4) = '0011')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,5, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 4)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,3) = '011')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,4, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 3)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,2) = '11')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,3, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 2)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,2) = '01') and len(@f_NormPhone) > 2
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,3, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 2)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,3) = '015')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,4, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 3)

IF (Left(@F_NormPhone,4) = '0015')
    select  @F_NormPhone = SUBSTRING(@F_NormPhone,5, LEN(@F_NormPhone) - 4)
```

Comment: Si te entendí bien, estas utilizando 2 funciones. Una que provoca que queden 4 ceros al final y otra para tratar de eliminar los ceros. Si este fuere el caso, lo que primero debes revisar es la función que deja los ceros al final, si ahí no puedes arreglarlo entonces ahí ya revisas la segunda función. Si te es posible muestra las funciones completas para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: uso una sola funcion, la misma me limpia el campo telefono. el numero deberia quedar con 8digitos . y me queda de 12 digitos, con 4 ceros al final. las lineas final de la funcion, las que publique, deberia sacar los ultimos 4 digitos que son los 0, pero no me lo hace

Comment: Creo que estás complicando la lógica, si el único problema son los 4 ceros finales, por que no haces `RIGHT(LEFT(@F_NormPhone, 10),8)`?

Comment: lo que me devuelve es "23232300" me saca los 2 primeros caracteres y los ultimos 2, el numero 23232323 es simbolico, la funcion es para normalizar numeros de telefonos

Comment: Por lo que dices, la entrada no tendría entonces el formato que has mencionado en tu pregunta: `11232323230000` sino más bien algo así `232323230000`, por otro lado esto `right(@F_NormPhone,8) = '0000')`  en realidad debiera ser así `right(@F_NormPhone,4) = '0000')`.

Answer (score 1):

Estimados quedó solucionado, la solución fue hacer un `update` por fuera de la función, ya que si esos 4 "0" (0000) pertenecían al número de teléfono, la función normalizadora de teléfonos dejaría de funcionar. O sea normalizaría pero con números incorrectos.

```
Update tabla1 set Telphone = left(Telphone,len(Telphone) - 4) where right(Telphone,4) = '0000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo que puede servirte, pero solo considerando que al inicio encuentres dos uno y al final 4 ceros.

```
 declare @vceross varchar(max)='11232323230000'
 declare @vlongitud int

 select @vlongitud=len(@vceross)

 IF (right(@vceross,4) = '0000')
 BEGIN
 SELECT @vceross=  SUBSTRING(@vceross,0,@vlongitud-3)
 END

 IF left(@vceross,2)='11'
 BEGIN
 SELECT @vceross=SUBSTRING(@vceross,3,len(@vceross))
 END
```